# Get The Characters Before And After The symbols "- or /" in php

Tags: php, regex

I have this code : 170-83746/2189

so to create a function, so that i can get the value before dash which is 170 and the value after dash which is 83746 and the value after slash which is 2189

I have read about regular expression in PHP but I couldn't understand that thing

please help me

thanks for the solution, I come out with my own style using your help. Here is my code:

```
$number = "170-83746/2189";

function slice_trim($num, $symbol) {

  if($symbol=='/')
  $reg = '#/(\d+)#';
  else
  $reg = '#(\d+)-#';

  preg_match($reg, $num, $match);

  return str_replace($symbol,"",$match[0]);
}


echo slice_trim($number,"/");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('#(\d+)-(\d+)/(\d+)#', $number, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1] . ', ' . $matches[2] . ', ' . $matches[3];
}
```

To learn about regular expressions (which you really should), see http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: thank for the solution. I come out with my own style using your help

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$number = "170-83746/2189";

$res = preg_split('#[/-]#', $number);
print_r($res);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 170
    [1] => 83746
    [2] => 2189
)
```